# How do you change the style of a bootstrap checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

ive been looking on how to change the style of a bootstrap checkbox, and HAVE CHECKED THE OTHER ATTEMPTS! Made on here however every single attempt has not been successful, so is there a way to successfully change the style of a bootstrap check box or a normal checkbox.

```
<label>text</label>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s12jx7su/

UPDATED

http://jsfiddle.net/s12jx7su/1/

Comment: its updated, css doesnt appear to do anything

Comment: can you be more specific about what the end result should look like?

Comment: just a simple white box with no border/1px solid black. No inset or other shadow effects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a [**demo bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/ugwCnanAfm) for custom checkboxes that I use, implementing bootstraps glyphicons for the icons. These degrade to ordinary checkboxes in IE8 without any additional code.

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"],
    .custom-checkbox > label{
        margin-bottom:0px !important;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked {
        position: absolute;
        left: -9999px;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 22px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left:0; 
        top: 50%;
        margin-top:-9px;
        width: 17px; 
        height: 17px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
        font: normal normal normal 12px/1 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        content: '\e013';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top:-7px;
        left: 2px;
        color: #94C947;
        xtransition: all .2s;
    }

    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"][data-indeterminate] + label:after,
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"][data-indeterminate] + label:after {
        content: '\2212';
        left: 2px;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
        box-shadow: none;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        border-color: #eeeeee;
        cursor: not-allowed;
        opacity: 1;
        color: #dadada;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
      color: #dadada; cursor: not-allowed;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
      color: #aaa; cursor: not-allowed;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
        border: 1px solid #66afe9;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    }
    .custom-checkbox > label:hover:before {
        border: 1px solid #88D2FF !important;
    }
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:hover:before,
    .custom-checkbox > [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:hover:before{
        border: 1px solid #E4E4E4 !important;
    }
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
    <label for="cb1">Fancy Checkbox</label>
 </div>
```

HTH, -Ted

Comment: incredible solution. Can you comment on compatability and if it will downgrade properly?

Comment: @coderVishal - because it uses selectors old browsers don't understand, it downgrades perfectly--as example, in IE8, you would see the normal checkbox.

Comment: Nice but how to change data-indeterminate ? for example add a different color. its not changing for me?

Answer (score 1):

here is an expmle of how to style `checkbox` within bootstrap 3 :

```
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
div {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"] {
    /* IE opacity hacks */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.cb-label {
    position: relative;
}
.cb-label:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent url(http://blog.parkji.co.uk/images/posts/styling-checkboxes/switch.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 41px;
    width: 143px;
    left: -150px
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .cb-label:before,
/* the .checked class is used by IE only */
input[type="checkbox"].checked ~ .cb-label:before {
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4922/)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly about the checkbox style, but you may consider using icons for each of checkbox state. For example http://fontawesome.io/icon/square-o/ for not checked state and http://fontawesome.io/icon/check-square-o/ for checked state.
For AngularJs it might be something like this:

```
<div ng-show="checked"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

<div ng-show="not-checked"><i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer seems like to much job.

add simple class

```
.checkbox_color {
color: green;
accent-color: currentcolor;
}
```

Comment: This changes the text color not the color of the checkbox.